# How to re-draw a single item inside a ListView which uses DataTriggers to select templates for ListViewItems?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, datatrigger

In my code, I only have one `ListView` element that goes over a bunch of conditions and `MultiDataTriggers` to determine the correct template for each `ListViewItem` that is supposed to be drawn on the display.

This `ListView` element defines a `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` which then defines a `ContentTemplate` property for each item and in this part, I have declared the conditions for selecting each template. [Code Shown Below]

From this design, my understanding is that the responsibility of creating the elements and drawing the appropriate template is on `ListView`'s shoulders, not the `ListViewItems`. Therefore, when I change something about the DataContext of `ListViewItems` and call "UpdateLayout()" on them, nothing happens because they don't know how else to re-draw themselves.

The changes that I make to `ListViewItems`' DataContexts, are made to the same properties that are important when choosing the right template in the beginning. So, the template itself needs to be changed, not the insides of the elements, and this is my problem.

There is an `Error` class and it has a property named `List<string> Suggestions` that may have some items inside of it or nothing. When choosing the template, `Suggestions.Count` is decisive.

```xml
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Suggestions.Count}"
                   Value="0" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
            Value="{StaticResource SingleSuggestionErrorTemplate}" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

In run-time, the users see a `ListViewItem` that has no "More Suggestions" box, but by using a button, they can add a new one for the item. Then, the `ListViewItem` has to be re-drawn and show the template that displays another set of elements which includes the "More Suggestions" box. Here's an example of code-behind for doing this and also the way I access the parent Items:

```cs
async private void SubmitUserSuggestionButton_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the Expander element.
            Visual exp = ((DependencyObject)e.Source).GetParent<Expander>();

            // Access the parent ListViewItem of the Expander
            ListViewItem LVItem = exp.GetParent<ListViewItem>();

            // Get the location of the Error inside document.
            Error LVItem_Error = (Error)LVItem.DataContext;

            if (LVItem_Error.Word == "something")
            {
                LVItem_Error.Suggestions.Add("Custom Suggestion!");
                // At this point, the previous template which showed no suggestions
                // is no longer valid and the template has to be chosen again,
                // based on the new count of the list.
                LVItem.UpdateLayout();
                return;
            }
        }
```

I have tried using `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` and failed. Also, I have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the collection and that has failed too. The problem with the second approach may be that `Collection.Add()` does NOT fire `PropertyChanged`, but I'm not entirely sure that if I handled that problem, it would be useful since the `ListViewItem` itself is not capable of deciding what template to choose and the upper-level `ListView` has to do that.

I should mention that I'm aware of `ListView.Items.Refresh()` and it works for my scenario, but it's not helpful because I don't want and need to re-draw every item inside the list.

At last, What I'm hoping to do is to tell the upper-level `ListView` to "Refresh" only one specific item of its collection, not the whole bunch. I'd be very grateful for any and all answers or pointers.

The ListView:

```xml
 <ListView Name="lvErrors">
            <!-- Main ListView Item Style -->
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                                    <ContentControl.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <!-- Definition of MultiDataTriggers and Conditions -->
                                                .
                                                .
                                                .
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make Suggestions  an `ObservableCollection<string>`. Then the `Count` property would fire a change notification when elements are added or removed, and hence `Binding="{Binding Suggestions.Count}"` would be triggered. No need to do any manual UI "refresh".

Comment: @Clemens
Thank you for your response and excuse my delay. You are right, I must have not implemented `ObservableCollection` correctly before. As you pointed out, I only had to change the `List` to an `ObservableCollection` without even needing to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for it. Best of regards.